# Running TestNG with Maven

Tags: maven, testng

I am trying to run TestNG/Selenium a specific test suite, but I can't get it to run the test.  The command I am running is:

```
 mvn test -Dsuitefile=admin_tests.xml
```

The admin_tests.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https:://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Administration - All">
    <test name="Users tab tests" thread-count="1">
        <packages>
            <package name="appOne.testcases.ui.admin.users.*"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
    <test name="User roles tab tests" thread-count="1">
        <packages>
            <package name="appOne.testcases.ui.admin.userRoles.*"/>
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The directory structure is:

```
/test-suites/admin_tests.xml
/src/test/java/appOne/testcases/ui/admin/users/users_testcase1.xml
/src/test/java/appOne/testcases/ui/admin/users/users_testcase2.xml
/src/test/java/appOne/testcases/ui/admin/users/users_testcase3.xml

/src/test/java/appOne/testcases/ui/admin/userRoles/userRoles_testcase1.xml
/src/test/java/appOne/testcases/ui/admin/userRoles/userRoles_testcase2.xml
/src/test/java/appOne/testcases/ui/admin/users/userRoles_testcase3.xml
```

Any help would really be appreciated as I don't understand what I am doing wrong.  When I run the command I get 0 tests run.

pom.xml is:

```
 version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.36</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.36</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.22.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.http-client/google-http-client-gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-gson</artifactId>
            <version>1.41.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependency for TestRail APIClient -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Comment: Why do you hold `xml` files under `/src/test/java/*`?

Comment: No, the test xml files are in ./test-suites.  The test implements (java) are in src/test/java/*

Comment: show your pom.xml

Comment: @AlexeyR. I have added the pom.xml file, there will be multiple/many testsuite options so I don't want to hard-code them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to fix your suite file. You have `https:://` in `DOCTYPE` so you need to fix it to `https://`

Then you cannot just set any property. You have to tell surefire plugin that you are going to use that one to specify your suite. Add the following section to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
...

<properties>
    ...
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M6</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
    ...
</properties>

...

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suitefile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Next finally since you are running `mvn` from project root you should specify the path from project root so that you should start everything with

```
mvn test -Dsuitefile=test-suites/admin_tests.xml
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved the issue and the answer was very informative/detailed